# SSRS - Embed Rich Text (including images) in report

Tags: ssrs, reporting

An application my organization is developing includes a rich text editor. The content from this editor (text, tables, images, etc.) is HTML5 and is saved to the database. I'd like to find a way of embedding all of this content into some SSRS reports (sometimes as the core content, others as a sub-report), but it appears that only a limited subset of HTML tags and CSS attributes is supported. Are there any better ways (or off the shelf components) to help me achieve this goal? (I am considering rendering the HTML to an image and embedding the whole image but can't imagine this will work well).
Thank you in advance!